# SQLite Database Representation

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a question concerning the handling of SQLite databases in Android.

I am programming an Application, which is doing some Data Reporting out of a SQLite Database.
These App consists of one Activity which owns serveral Fragments.
These Fragments offer various tools to plot and manipulate data and communicate via Interfaces.

I also need one or several classes to represent my database and offer CRUD functions.

But now I don't know where to implement these classes.
Does every Fragment implement its own class, or should I place them central in my Activity and offer the CRUD functions via Interfaces?
I would do it with Interfaces, but since i have never done something with Android, im not sure.

Is there a recommended way or a pattern for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to use the activity to handle the database activities and writing/reading and just have your fragments communicate with the activity (this is recommended by google anyway). You DBOpenHelper could look something like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Dev Paul
 */
public class DataBaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



  // Logcat tag
    private static final String LOG = "DatabaseHelper";

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

//Table Names
public static final String REPS_TABLE = "repsTable";


//Reps Table Columns
public static final String R_COLUMN_ID = "repId";
public static final String R_COLUMN_STRING_DATA = "repStringData";
public static final String R_COLUMN_GOOD_FORM = "repGoodForm";

/**
 * Table create statements for the reps objects.
 */
private static final String CREATE_REPS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + REPS_TABLE + " (" + R_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER, "
        + R_COLUMN_STRING_DATA + " TEXT, "
        + R_COLUMN_GOOD_FORM + " INTEGER " + ")";
/**
 * Default constructor.
 * @param context from the calling activity.
 */
public DataBaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_REPS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //drop the tables if they exist.
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + REPS_TABLE);
    // create new tables
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

This is part of one of my apps that I'm working on and will eventually probably be open source anyway. Then your DataSource class could look something like this...

```
/**
 * Created by Dev Paul
 */
public class DataSource {

private Context mContext;
private DataBaseOpenHelper dataBaseOpenHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private boolean isOpened;

/**
 * Class that helps with obtaining data from the data base. This should do all interfacing to
 * the data base. No calls should be directly made to {@code DataBaseOpenHelper}.
 * @param context the context of the calling activity.
 */
public DataSource(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    dataBaseOpenHelper = new DataBaseOpenHelper(context);
}

/**
 * Checks to see if the database has been openned.
 * @return
 */
public boolean isOpened() {
    return isOpened;
}

/**
 * Get a writeable database. This must be called.
 */
public void open() {
    db = dataBaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    isOpened = true;
}

/**
 * Close the database. This must be called.
 */
public void close() {
    dataBaseOpenHelper.close();
    isOpened = false;
}

    //handle getting and creating data methods....
}
```

Then you just need to handle getting the setting the data using query statements with proper SQL syntax. So in your activity you would just have to create a new DataSource object and call dataSource.open() to open the database. Then in your `onDestroy()` method of your activity call dataSource.close() so that you don't leak any elements.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply maintain a singleton instance of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` and use it in your fragments where ever you want.

Singleton instance is recommended for data-centric applications. Even if you have multiple threads working on the same database instance, you don't need to worry about synchronization. Since you have a single instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` , you are internally maintaining single instance of `SQLiteDatabase` object and it is thread safe.

You have just mentioned about multiple fragments inside an activity(Not mentioned about thread used for processing data). So I would like to add upon that aspect.
Better do data-centric operations on background threads. When each fragment does some processing on data - it is highly recommended to do in background thread to avoid blocking UI/Main thread.

To organize your code better, create a DAO layer.